# Rails: Sort two different models (tables) together with multiple criterias

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two different models (Container and StockReceipt) that I need to merge and order for displaying in a table as deliveries. I'm currently sorting the records in the controller:

> stock_receipts = StockReceipt.where(:delivery_date.gt => 1.month.ago)
>
> containers = Container.joins(:shipment).where(:shipment => {:etd.gt => 1.month.ago})
>
> @deliveries = (stock_receipts + containers).sort!{|a,b| delivery_date(a) <=>
> delivery_date(b)}

delivery_date being an helper method that returns the date according the class

It works but I would like to sub-sort by supplier (in SQL: ORDER BY delivery_date, supplier_id). I could group_by(delivery_date).group_by(supplier) but it's a bit ugly.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this either in Rails or directly in SQL.

Thanks guys,
Gam

Comment: Can you put your table structure and tell me how you are ,"pulling records from both models from the DB then doing in the controller"

Answer (score 1):

You could use search engine like Solr and Sunspot gem(http://sunspot.github.com/) which supports multi-model search

Here is a small example:

```
search = Sunspot.search(Post,Comment) do
  with(:published_at).less_than(Time.now)
  paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Sunspot is clearly able to do this, thanks. However, I feel it's a bit overkill here.